# Add a custom option through event observer for a specific product type, in Magento-2.1.7

Tags: product, magento-2.1.7

I have created a custom product type as "mycustomtype", programmatically. 
Now, I want to add a text area as custom option for a specific product type, through an event observer.

In detail,

Whenever the admin adds a new product, selecting the product type as "mycustomtype", I want a custom option(Text Area), that appear automatically for those "mycustomtype" products. To achieve this, I have written an observer for the event `catalog_product_save_after` and in my observer file , my execute function looks like the following,

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {  

    if($_product->getTypeId()=='mycustomtype' && $_product->isObjectNew()==1) {  

        $_product       = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $productId = $_product->getId();

        $options = [
            'title' => 'Enter Message',
            'type' => 'field',
            'is_require' => 1,
            'sort_order' => 1,
        ];

        $customOptions = [];
        $this->objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customOptionFactory = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterfaceFactory');
        $customOption = $customOptionFactory->create(['data' => $options]);
        $customOption->setProductSku($_product->getSku());
        $customOption->setOptionId(null);
        $customOptions[] = $customOption;
        $product =  $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    }
}
```

When the observer is fired, the execution takes a long time and gives me an error as follows,

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.